# With OOP PHP, how can I get an updated object without instantiating it again?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a User class (simplified):

```
class User { 

   public int $ID; 
   public string $email; 
   public string $firstName; 

   public function __construct( int $userId = 0 ) {
      
      $user = get_user_by( "id", $userId ); 

      $this->ID = $userId; 
      $this->email = $user->data->user_email;
      $this->firstName = get_user_meta( $userId, "first_name", true );

   }

   public function set_first_name( string $firstName ) {
      return update_user_meta( $this->ID, "first_name", $firstName );
   }

}
```

To register a new member, I use the function below. Basically:

1. I create a new user;
2. I instantiate my User class;
3. I use a method that updates the user's first name provided by the User class;
4. I instantiate the User class again and return it. If I don't instantiate the class again, and return the class I instantiated earlier, I get an outdated object (without the user's first name).

My question is: is there a way to return the updated object without instantiating the User class again? (Instantiating it again looks like a bit of a waste since the `get_user_by` function in the constructor runs again, which is superfluous).

```
function register( array $data = [] ) {
           
   $userId = wp_insert_user([
      "user_login" => $data["email"],
      "user_email" => $data["email"],
      "user_pass" => $data["password"]
   ]); 

   if( is_wp_error( $userId ) ) {
      return new \WP_Error( "create_user_err", $userId->get_error_message() ); 
   }

   $User = new User( $userId );

   if( ! empty( $data["firstName"] ) ) {
      $User->set_first_name( $data["firstName"] );
   }      

   // How do I return the updated object without instantiating User again? 

   return new User( $userId );

}
```

Comment: You are not setting the new value for the object property anywhere. `$this->firstName = $firstName;` inside your `set_first_name` method, before the return statement, would achieve this. (Whether such a method should do both of those things, set the property, and make a database update, at the same time, would be a different question.)

Comment: Ah, I get it, thanks. You made me curious though: should the method both set the property and update the database or not?

Comment: That's a bit hard to say, in this environment. With a proper ORM implementation, your getter and setter functions would only get/set object properties, and updating the actual record in the database, would then be the job of the _persistence manager._ But since WP doesn't have anything like that, in this situation it might also be okay to have the setter method update the database directly. (If it is clear to all parties who will ever be using this, that it deviates from the "standard" in this aspect.)

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell what you're higher level objective is, but let's remove the WP functions from inside the class and go from there.

`set_first_name()` method is not setting the object's `$firstName` property.

To demonstrate how to set and retrieve a property, let's fetch the WP values before we instantiate the class, and instantiate the class with id and email.

```
<?php

class User
{
    public int $ID;
    public ?string $email;
    public ?string $firstName;

    public function __construct(int $userId = 0, string $email = null)
    {
        $this->ID = $userId;
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function setFirstName(?string $firstName)
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;
    }

    public function getFirstName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }
}

// Note, I don't know how these WP functions work
// I'm just making assumptions that your use of them is accurate
function register(array $data = [])
{
    $userId = wp_insert_user([
        "user_login" => $data["email"],
        "user_email" => $data["email"],
        "user_pass" => $data["password"]
    ]);

    if (is_wp_error($userId)) {
        return new \WP_Error("create_user_err", $userId->get_error_message());
    }

    $wpUser = get_user_by("id", $userId);
    $myUser = new User($userId, $data["email"]);

    if (!empty($data["firstName"])) {
        $myUser->setFirstName($data["firstName"]);
    }

    // How do I return the updated object without instantiating User again? 
    return $myUser->getFirstName();
}
```

Note that since `firstName` is public, you can also set and get it directly if you wanted to. i.e. `$myUser->firstName = 'foo';`